# HashMap sorting

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have a

```
HashMap<String,Integer> wordMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

I need to print the elements in such a way that they are in decreasing order of Integer values and the if two strings have same Integer values, they must be displayed in alphabetical order.
i.e If

HashMap={(it,2),(worst,1),(the,2),(of,2)}

,
The output should be::

```
it-2
of-2
the-2
worst-1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `LinkedHashMap` and compare the items' individual values, by starting with the item at index 0 as the baseline.